# Em qual parte da aplicação é mais apropriado reordenar um array (banco de dados, aplicação no servidor, código cliente)?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, array

Suponhamos que, numa consulta ao banco de dados MYSQL, eu precise de pegar os últimos 1000 dados lançados, porém, dentro desses resultados exibidos, **a ordem dele deve ser crescente** (e não decrescente, como aconteceria no `ORDER BY ID DESC Limit 1000`).

A resposta desses dados será via **JSON**, através da função `json_encode` do **PHP**, em uma url específica, onde quem vai capturar e processar esses dados é o **Javascript**.

A pergunta que eu tenho é a seguinte:
Considerando os exemplos 1, 2 e 3 e tendo em vista que os dados devem vir formatados em ordem reversa, qual dessas seria a maneira mais apropriada, levando em consideração o consumo de memória e a velocidade de processamento dos dados ?

*1 - MYSQL*

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, pessoa_id, chat 
    FROM chat 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000
) AS reverse_chat ORDER BY id ASC
```

*2 - PHP*

```
return Response::json(array_reverse($chat)); //lembrando que é $chat é um array com 1000 dados
```

*3 - Javascript*

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_response',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {pessoa_id: pessoa_id},
    success: function(response){
        // response também possui 1000 dados
        var html = _.template(tpl_chat, {chat: response.reverse()});

    }
})
```

Comment: A opção `1` é a melhor.

Comment: Não me parece ser uma pergunta construtiva na forma atual. Talvez ela possa ser melhorada para deixar claro sua necessidade real. Se você vai consultar no banco de dados faça com SQL. Se tem que fazer em um *browser*, faça com JS e se estiver entre um e outro, faça com PHP.

Comment: Quanto mais cedo os dados forem tratados e organizados melhor para a eficiência da aplicação. No teu caso prático se os dados são provenientes de uma base de dados e podes ordenar os mesmos ao realizar a consulta, sem duvida votar no comentário do @Sergio.

Comment: @bigown, como citado no exemplo, estou partindo do pressuposto que vou usar os três : Mysql na consulta, PHP na resposta, javascript no processamento. Só quero saber qual desses é mais rápido e qual gastará menos memória.

Comment: Exatamente, não existe uma pergunta real. Por isto a pergunta não é construtiva. Você quer saber algo que não tem relevância. Pelo menos isto não está claro na pergunta e o comentário não melhorou essa percepção.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters como assim usar os três? A pergunta é sobre qual a melhor linguagem para ordenar a informação, certo? e isso só precisa fazer uma vez, certo? aí a resposta é sem duvida a opção 1. Ou estou a perceber errado?

Comment: O título era um chamatorio para votos de fechamento. "Melhor" é muito questão de opinião. Troquei por algo mais técnico e factível, ok?

Comment: Obrigado, @Renan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuide da ordenação o mais cedo possível. No seu caso, isso quer dizer no banco de dados.

> levando em consideração o consumo de memória e a velocidade de processamento dos dados

Não é possível levar isso em consideração de maneira genérica, vai depender das características da sua aplicação e do seu BD. Se tiver problemas de performance com essa query e não for possível otimizá-la (reformulando a query ou criando índices), passe para o próximo nível (no caso, o PHP).